# Adding a background behind a .mov with transparency (and then converting to mp4)

Tags: ffmpeg

I am struggling with adding a solid background to a transparent .mov video. Notably, that there seems to be no limit to the frames that are generated when run. My command:

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i color=lightgrey:s=1690x3000 -filter_complex 'overlay=0:0' -i Male-Nervous-System.mov -c:v libx264 -b:v 2000k -pass 1 -an -f mp4 /dev/null && ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=lightgrey:s=1690x3000 -filter_complex 'overlay=0:0' -i Male-Nervous-System.mov -c:v libx264 -b:v 2000k -pass 2 -movflags faststart -c:a aac -b:a 128k ../mp4/Male-Nervous-System.mp4
```

What am I missing to constrain the length of the lightgrey background image/video to the length of the other video (around 5 seconds)?

Answer (score 0):

The overlay filter, by default, runs as long as the longer of the two inputs. The color filter is indefinite, so overlay has to be told to stop with the shortest stream.

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i color=lightgrey:s=1690x3000 -i Male-Nervous-System.mov -filter_complex 'overlay=0:0:shortest=1' -c:v libx264 -b:v 2000k -pass 1 -an -f mp4 /dev/null &&
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=lightgrey:s=1690x3000 -i Male-Nervous-System.mov -filter_complex 'overlay=0:0:shortest=1' -c:v libx264 -b:v 2000k -pass 2 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -movflags faststart  ../mp4/Male-Nervous-System.mp4
```